# How to display a product on thesame page as the product list using $_SESSION variables? PHP, HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I Have an e-commerce page as a project for my uni.
All of the pages of the site are located in one index.php as slides.
my problem is displaying a product on witch the user clicked.
slide 3 is product list which displays all of the products just fine.
after you click on the product the link is going to take you to slide 7 which is a products page where i will be loading the product based in on its id in the database.

I have tried a lot of things too make this work.

My prof said that the best way to do this would be with $_SESSION variable but i dont get how i can do it.
Can anyone give me at least a tip on how to solve this problem.

For example How would i display the name of the product in H2 of slide 7 using SESSION?

```
     <div class="slide" id="3">
                <?php
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "");

                mysqli_select_db($con, "users");
                $sql = "select * from Products where featured=1";
                $featured = $con->query($sql);
                ?>
                <div class="content third-content">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                                <?php
                                ?>
                                <?php while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)): ?>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="featured-item"> 
                                            <a href="#7" id="p_click"><img src="<?= $product['image']; ?>" alt=""></a>
                                            <div class="down-content">
                                                <h4><?= $product['title']; ?></h4>

                                                <h5><?= $product['s_description']; ?></h5>

                                                <h6>€<?= $product['price']; ?></h6>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
       </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is where you are sent after you click on the product(a.e the link).

```
 <div class="slide" id="7" >
                <div class="content seventh-content">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <form id="product" action="" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">


                                    <h2></h2>

                                </div>
                           </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your 'a' tag to set the id of product clicked in the url as:

```
<a href="?productId=<?php echo $product['id'];?>#7" id="p_click"><img src="<?= $product['image']; ?>" alt=""></a>
```

After that you can check if product id has been set in the url or not as :

```
isset($_GET['productId'])
```

If productId has been set, it means that product was clicked and now we should fetch data for that product.

And you could make your slide section like this:

```
    <?php if(isset($_GET['productId'])) : ?>
<?php
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "");
                $prodId = $_GET['productId'];
                mysqli_select_db($con, "users");
                $sql = "select * from Products where id='$prodId'";
                $query = $con->query($sql);
                ?>

                <?php while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)): ?>
                    <div class="slide" id="7" >
                <div class="content seventh-content">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <form id="product" action="" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">


                                    <h2><?php echo $product["title"]; ?></h2>

                                </div>
                           </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: There is one thing tho. Maybe you know the reason this happens. Using this method sets slide 7 as the main slide a.e."Home". So it messes with jQuery. Maybe there is a way to prevent that?

Comment: I am not sure how you are handling the tabs selection, maybe if you could post the code for how you are setting the slides as main or not , then I could help.